# C# LINQ Filter records in child tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have a main table "SALES" and two secondary tables "PRODUCTS" and "SERVICES", I need to select only the records in "SALES" that contain some product or service entered by the user, I don't need to bring the sales records and products, just filter. First I made the filter in the table "SALES" by date of sale:

```
var query = (from p in _contexto.sales
where p.datesale.Value.Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(strDtI).Date &&
p.datesale.Value.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(strDtF).Date
select p);
```

Now let's say the user wants to filter also the sales that have products or services with the words in a string Array

```
words = ['apple', 'beef', 'cleaning', 'haircut']
```

if you receive the array of words, I tried the filter below, but it didn't work, it kept bringing all the records.

```
var queryi = (from i in _contexto.products
where words.Contains(i.name) || words.Contains(i.description) select i);
//var queryj = (from i in _contexto.services
//where words.Contains(i.name) || words.Contains(i.description) select i);

//query = query.Where(p => queryi.All(c => c.idsale != p.id) || queryj.All(c => c.idsale != p.id));
query = query.Where(p => queryi.All(c => c.idsale != p.id));
```

where am I failing, and is there a better and more performant way to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Your `queryi` seems backwards to me: did you intend to get products that have a name or description that is exactly one of the entry in the `words` array? (Also, why do you use range variable names that don't match their data sources? (e.g. `p` for sales and `c` for products???)

Comment: Your last query has a problem - you are testing all the matching products sold don't match a single sale's id - that can never happen. You want to do the opposite - see if the sale's `id` is in the matching products `idsale` collection: `Where(s => matchingProducts.Select(p => p.idsale).Contains(s.id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using more descriptive variable names, and assuming you meant to only find products that have the exact same name or description as one of the `words`, you would have:

```
var salesInPeriod = from s in _contexto.sales
                    where Convert.ToDateTime(strDtI).Date <= s.datesale.Value.Date &&
                          s.datesale.Value.Date <= Convert.ToDateTime(strDtF).Date
                    select s;

var matchingidsales = from p in _contexto.products
                      where words.Contains(p.name) || words.Contains(p.description)
                      select p.idsale;

var ans = from s in salesInPeriod
          where matchingidsales.Contains(s.id)
          select s;
```

PS: I inverted the date comparison since I think it makes it easier to see you are doing a between test.